# Install C++ program with automake and autoconf

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, automake

I've made a program in C++, but now I must install this program with autoconf and automake.

So, when I run command "./configure && make && make install", it must do the following:

- compile program
- create folder my_program inside /opt (example: /opt/my_program/) and in this folder I must also have all static libraries and source files
- There must be symbolic link in /usr/local/bin for my_program
- Libraries must be in /usr/local/lib (DONE - Thanks to @Galik )
- Header files of my_program must be in /usr/local/include (DONE)

I've wrote this configure.ac script:

```
#                                               -*- Autoconf -*-
# Process this file with autoconf to produce a configure script.

AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([my_program], [0.1], [my_mail])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([AbsAlgorithm.hpp])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE

# Checks for programs.
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_PROG_CC

# Checks for libraries.

# Checks for header files.
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([stdlib.h string.h sys/time.h unistd.h wchar.h wctype.h])

# Checks for typedefs, structures, and compiler characteristics.
AC_CHECK_HEADER_STDBOOL
AC_C_INLINE
AC_TYPE_SIZE_T

# Checks for library functions.
AC_FUNC_MALLOC
AC_FUNC_MKTIME
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([gettimeofday memset mkdir])

LIBS="-ldl"

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

and this Makefile.am script:

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign

AM_CXXFLAGS=-Wall -std=gnu++11 -DVERSION=\"$(VERSION)\" -DPROG="\"$(PACKAGE)\""

bin_PROGRAMS = algatorc
noinst_LIBRARIES = libalgatorc.a
libalgatorc_a_SOURCES = Timer.cpp
include_HEADERS = Timer.hpp TestSetIterator.hpp TestCase.hpp ETestSet.hpp EParameter.hpp Entity.hpp ParameterSet.hpp AbsAlgorithm.hpp Log.hpp JSON.hpp
algatorc_SOURCES = ParameterSet.cpp TestCase.cpp EParameter.cpp ETestSet.cpp TestSetIterator.cpp Entity.cpp Timer.cpp  main.cpp JSON.cpp JSONValue.cpp
```

Now, when I run "./configure && make && make install" I don't get new folder called my_program in /opt. But, I now, I do have header files in /usr/local/include. I don't have lib files in /usr/local/lib. There is just one folder for python. I would like to have folder called my_program and inside that folder I would like to have static libs.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 x64

I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: *"I don't have lib files in /usr/local/lib"* - you don't make any libraries.

Comment: I've edited my post (actually I've edited my Makefile.am). I still don't have lib in /usr/local/lib.

Comment: The `noinst_` part of `noinst_LIBRARIES` means "do not install". Try using `lib_LIBRARIES` instead.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you very much. But is it posible to create folder inside /usr/local/lib and to put lib in that folder? For example I would like lib file to be in /usr/local/lib/algatorc/ . Is that possible? If not, then this is ok ;)
Do you also know how to do this? create folder my_program inside /opt (example: /opt/my_program/) and in this folder I must also have all static libraries and source files

Comment: @golobich: A non-standard target directory (like `/opt/my_program`) is usually selected at configure time via `--prefix`. I'd be pretty miffed by a package that overruled that selection with a hardcoded path.

Comment: yes, thank you. this is the command I was searching for: ./configure --prefix=/opt/my_program
Could you or @Galik please post an answer and include in answer this for --prefix and that what Galik said about libraries? So I could accept answer. Thank you very much for your help! :)

Comment: I was working on a fuller explanation, now posted. Hope its clear enough. You can also go to `IRC Freenode #autotools` and get help there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autotools is not really designed to put things in specific locations. The idea is that programs go in the *programs directory* `$(bindir)`, libraries in the *libraries directory* `$(libdir)` etc and that the person installing everything gets to decide where those locations are.

So you should really only care about installing things relative to wherever the person running the installer wants them to be.

They do this by adding arguments to the `configure` script like:

```
configure --prefix=/opt/myprog
```

That will typically install programs in `/opt/myprog/bin` and libraries in `/opt/myprog/lib` etc...

You can add to the places that things get installed by setting special `dir` variables. For example to put libraries in a sub-directory of `$(libdir)` (default /usr/local/lib) you caan do:

```
myprog_librarydir = $(libdir)/myprog
```

And its not uncommon to do the same for the header files:

```
myprog_includedir = $(prefix)/include/myprog
```

That defines some destination folders you can refer to instead of the defaults:

```
myprog_include_HEADERS = \
    Timer.hpp \
    TestSetIterator.hpp \
    TestCase.hpp \
    ETestSet.hpp \
    EParameter.hpp \
    Entity.hpp \
    ParameterSet.hpp \
    AbsAlgorithm.hpp \
    Log.hpp \
    JSON.hpp
```

Those will now get installed into `$(prefix)/include/myprog`.

Similarly with the corresponding library:

```
myprog_library_LIBRARIES = libmyprog.a

libmyprog_a_SOURCES = \
    ParameterSet.cpp \
    TestCase.cpp \
    EParameter.cpp \
    ETestSet.cpp \
    TestSetIterator.cpp \
    Entity.cpp \
    Timer.cpp \
     JSON.cpp \
    JSONValue.cpp
```

So basically you create a destination (installation) directory using:

```
mynamedir = $(prefix)/path/... whatever
```

That allows you to set destinations other than `bin_`, `lib_` and `include_` etc...

So instead of saying `lib_LIBRARIES` you can say `myname_LIBRARIES`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you very much! :)